# vertical seekbar behaving abnormally

Tags: android, seekbar

[image]    package android.widget;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends SeekBar {

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public VerticalSeekBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(h, w, oldh, oldw);
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(-90);
        c.translate(-getHeight(), 0);

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                setProgress(getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight()));
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I customized my seek bar using the code above. The thumb of my seekbar is showing upside down. i.e thumb is behaving just in reverse direction as it should behave normally. When my listview is at the start, the thumb is at the last position of the seekbar and vice versa. HELP!!!!!!!

[image]

Comment: can you post a sample screenshot of how it behaves?

Comment: the thumb should have been at the top.. but it is showing at the bottom.. and as the listview scrolls down the thumb goes up.. which is just the reverse behavior.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a Inverted Seekbar implementation from the same code. While this works for Vertical Seek bar I just tried a inverted one which should be helpful in your case. I have added my project to github and here is the link to it.

https://github.com/AndroSelva/Vertical-SeekBar-Android

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
        c.rotate(90);
        c.translate(0, -getWidth());

        super.onDraw(c);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (!isEnabled()) {
            return false;
        }

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                int i=0;
                i=getMax() - (int) (getMax() * event.getY() / getHeight());
                setProgress(100-i);
                Log.i("Progress",getProgress()+"");
                onSizeChanged(getWidth(), getHeight(), 0, 0);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. Thank u very much..
I changed:
c.rotate(90);
        c.translate(0, -getWidth());
and this helped.